# Vim "write with sudo" not working

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, vim

I'm editing a system-wide file called `ssh_config` in `/etc/ssh` folder using `vi` without root privilege. And I save this file by using the following command:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting this error

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

then I try another command by explicitly provide `root` password.

```
:w !echo password | sudo -S tee %
```

And a warning show

```
W12: Warning: File "user_config" has changed and the buffer was changed in Vim as well
See ":help W12" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

I already try all the above options but none of these work. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether if it has an impact on the right diagnosis, but you named both `vi` and `vim` as the editor you use. Which one is it, actually?

Comment: Also what terminal / console are you opening the editor in?

Answer (score 2):

If you edit the file, THEN decide you need to be `root`, your process needs improvement.

Think before you type.

Read
`man sudoedit`, set up your `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` environment variables, and it's easy.

In emergencies ("I typed 97 lines of config and it won't let me save!"), save the file somewhere else (where you have write permission) `:w/tmp/oops`, exit the editor and use `sudo cp /tmp/oops !$` to copy it to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Due to a design change, neovim [doesn't yet support](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496) interactive sessions through an external program via a bang command so the `:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null` approach for saving as a different user with sudo [doesn't work](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12103) like it does in vim.

A solution is to use the [suda.vim](https://github.com/lambdalisue/suda.vim) plugin instead.